# YPDrawSignatureView - Table scrolling when drawing signature

Tags: swift, scroll, cell

So I want a signature view within a table cell. Obviously whenever somebody tries to draw in the cell, the table scrolls.

How would I stop the scrolling but ONLY when the user is writing in the signature box?

Comment: You should probably accept an answer if it is helpful. If not, then elaborate your question with more information, that way you can get the help you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve this with a button covering the cell, and when the user taps it, the cell displays the YPDrawSignatureView. Just before the signature view is shown, disable the scrolling:

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = false
```

Later when you save the signature, enable scrolling again by setting scrollEnabled to **true**.

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you

Comment: No problem. Nice to see my project is used.

Comment: Its a brilliant solution to quite a simple problem. Thanks again!

Comment: What if user don't save the signature and wants to scroll the tableview to display other cell? I am facing same issue because I have more than one signature view in my tableview I am facing issue like signature view is always open and user can do signature in any cell by that time he also must be able to scroll to other cells without saving the signature

Answer (score 5):

I found better solution for this issue rather than putting button. Implement the delegate methods in viewController,

```
class mainVC: UIViewController,YPSignatureDelegate {
```

Than set delegate of signature view to this view controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SignatureCell", for: indexPath) as! SignatureCell
            cell.signatureView.delegate = self
            return cell
}
```

And then add these code. This are two delegates of YPSignature. Add in Main view controller

```
    func didStart() {
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
    // didFinish() is called rigth after the last touch of a gesture is registered in the view.
    // Can be used to enabe scrolling in a scroll view if it has previous been disabled.
    func didFinish() {
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a uitableview and custom cells. In one of the custom cells contain a button(ex. addSignatureButton) on the top of signatureView.

I used delegate method to communicate between uitableviewcell and uiviewcontroller. A delegate is added to UITableViewCell to notify whether the addSignatureButton is tapped. Once it is tapped, addSignatureButton is hidden, signatureView is visible and the tableview's scroll is disabled. When user finishes adding signature, signatureView is hidden, addSignatureButton is visible and tableview scroll is enabled.

https://github.com/alvinvgeorge/DrawSignatureOnTableViewCell